# How to mock global variable in Jest test?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

In my `Jest` test case, I want to mock one global variable, but I am getting `Cannot assign to '' because it is an import.` . How to fix that?

I want to cover a scenario where I do have valid `token` then do something.

Tried this but no luck:

- `jest.mock('jwtToken', () => () => ({ jwtToken: 'abc' }));`

Service.ts

```
export let token: string;

@Injectable()
    export class MyService {
      constructor(
      ) {
        token = null;
      }
    
    
      /**
       * Checks token expiration to avoid N calls to generate token.
       * @returns token status
       */
      public async myFunction() {
        try {
          if (token) {
          // Do something
          }
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      }
    }
```

Service.spec.ts

```
import { MyService, token } from './authz.service';

describe('MyService', () => {
  let myService: MyService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.resetModules();


    myService = new MyService();
  });

  describe('myFunction()', () => {

    it('My test case', async () => {
     
      token = 123; // Cannot assign to 'jwtToken' because it is an import.

      const output = await myService.myFunction();
      expect(output).toEqual(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of mocking global variables in jest.

First: jest.spyOn

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get').mockImplementation(() => ({
  token: '123',
}));
```

Second: Object.defineProperty

```
Object.defineProperty(global.window, 'token', {
   get() {
      return '123';
   }
});
```

The recommended one is jest.spyOn because it takes into account cleanup and doesn't pollute the global scope.

Comment: how it's related to my code? :)

Comment: the only thing I need to mock is 'Rooty = {}' in Childy